# Notification emails on Android App purchases as developer

Tags: android, google-checkout, email-notifications, android-billing

Is there a way for a Google Android developer to get email notifications whenever a user purchases my app(s)?

I know there's a Google Checkout purchase history, but would prefer email notifications.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why this is down voted. There is not such option in the developer console or Google Checkout. If you are processing your IAB orders on your own server, you can send notifications your self. You could also poll the Checkout API and send notifications periodically.

Comment: Too bad this is still the case. I wanted to get vibrations whenever someone makes an in-app purchase for fun.